# Docker-compose with urwid (ncurses) Python app

Tags: python, docker-compose, python-asyncio, tui, urwid

I am creating an algorithm that needs to run on a server, along with a small database.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    command: python -u app.py
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.1

COPY . /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The app is an ncurses (urwid) app which transforms the terminal into a TUI to monitor the algorithm. When I run the app separately on my laptop, it works as expected with the terminal turning into the TUI. When ran with the command "docker-compose up", the terminal first shows stdout from docker and mongo, after which certain (clipped) parts of the TUI start to show. The TUI components are malformed and unresponsive. Killing the docker process keeps the clipped parts in the terminal.

*Possible hint*:
The TUI contains a running clock with hrs:min:sec. When the clipped parts appear the clock is correct but it freezes immediately. The clock is updated by an underlying asyncio event loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app_db:
    container_name: appDB
    image: mongo:latest

  app:
    command: python -u /usr/src/app/app.py
    container_name: app
    build: .
    links:
    - app_db
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

When running *docker-compose run app*, both the app and the mongo container are running and I get a terminal interface into the app container.